# SqlAlchemy: Join onto another object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My little website has a table of comments and a table of votes. Each user of the website gets to vote once on each comment.

When displaying comments to the user, I will select from the comments table and outerjoin a vote if one exists for the current user.

Is there a way to make a query where the vote will be attached to the comment through comment.my_vote ?

The way I'm doing it now, the query is returning a list for each result - [comment, vote] - and I'm passing that directly to my template. I'd prefer if the vote could be a child object of the comment.

Comment: Can you post your code? It would be helpful if you pare it down to three things: the sqlalchemy definitions, the current code being passed to the template, and some pseudocode illustrating what you'd rather be passing to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided that working with the tuple returned by the query wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Setup your model to add a [One-to-one relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#one-to-one). Sample code from the link verbatim:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, backref="parent", 
        # lazy='joined', # @note: optional: uncomment this to have the 'child' always loaded when the parent is loaded.
    )

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

in your case `Parent` would be `Comment` and `Child` would be `Vote`.
Then you can query for `Comment`, at the same time eagerly loading the `Vote`. For this it would recomment just to uncomment the commented out line above, so that your query will return all in just one `SQL` statement. Alternatively you can specify loading of the `Vote` in the query explicitly using [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload):

```
res = query(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.child))
```

Comment: it's not 1 to 1, as multiple users can vote on the same comment